# Modifying question to suit answer would obsolete comments

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/why-do-some-flight-attendants-have-call-signs) which had an unrelated, but excellent answer.

I'd like to modify the question title to make it match the answer (and also to be able to ask the original question again more clearly, in hope someone will answer it), but this will make some comments obsolete, and I don't want to annoy the people who made them.

What is the best course of action in this case? Should I just accept the fact that some comments will be stale? Should I keep a small "edit" in the end to state "this has originally been asked as bla bla"?

Answer (score 10):

Comments are expendable by design; they are frequently removed as a matter of keeping the site clean. You won't annoy the people making the comments -- they'd be probably annoyed (if at all) at the moderator removing them (and that probably will be me ;))

So, change the question as you deem fit.

However, changing the question to such an extent that the *answers* are no longer valid is a different matter altogether -- avoid it when possible, and if the question is to be changed so much that the answers won't match it, it might be better to ask another question altogether instead of editing the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are "second class" citizens on this, and other SE sites.

ANSWERS are the key, so you do want to bring your question in line with one or more answers. Comments only help to "get to" answers, and can be removed at any time. Don't worry about them.